# Localhost subfolder PHP

Tags: php, directory, localhost

I have a problem with my localhost website.

So I explain here my problem, I have a folder in localhost/sg/ with all php file. If i want to show a picture I should use /sg/upload/myfile.jpg for example.

But If I upload my php file on my server that's doesn't work, because I don't have a /sg/ folder in my www folder.

So my question is, it's possible to have a script who can manage this for offline and online?

If you have question, don't hesitate.

Thank you.

Comment: your accept ratio is 50%, please go to your questions and accept one appropriate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set upload path relative to your site path
for example define a constant:

offline:

```
<?php
define ("SITEPATH","http://localhost/sg/upload/");
<?
```

online:

```
<?php
define ("SITEPATH","http://www.yoursite.com/upload/");
<?
```

then use this constant (SITEPATH) to locate the file upload destination

```
<?php
$destination = SITEPATH.$filename;
?>
```

Comment: @Julien_he: There is also [`__FILE__` and `__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) without doing anything on your behalf. You should prefer convention over configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a config file that sets the path for your images, and other files, dynamically depending on whether the site is local or on production.

Comment: You should favour convention over configuration, because you don't need to configure that, the site structure itself [does not differ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10622028/367456).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is more related to your web server (Apache?) than PHP.

I guess the answer to your problem is a proper configuration in your (Apache?) files, more specifically with the DocumentRoot directive both in production and developing servers

Answer (score 0):

Cant you also upload the image folder `/sg/upload/` to your production server? When publishing programs, the dependencies also need to be published. In your case, that folder is your project's dependency. EIther you need to use config files like John has suggested to specify the different upload folder for production environment or you need to simply upload that folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Typically only the basedir differs, but not the site structure:

```
development: http://localhost/project-blue/

production:  http://project-blue.example.com/
```

In that directory you place a PHP file, let's say `index.php`:

```
http://localhost/project-blue/index.php
```

If it should display a URL to an uploaded picture called `upload/picture.jpg`, you only need to link it properly:

```
<img src="upload/picture.jpg">
```

Which will then make the browser obtain this this URL:

```
 http://localhost/project-blue/upload/picture.jpg
```

That will work on both, development and production:

```
 http://project-blue.example.com/upload/picture.jpg
```

So actually there is not much you need to care about here.